# Unable to pass value from parent to child component in angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript

Basically scenario is, i am shifting the value of variable up to its grand-parent component using EventEmitter (till now its working fine).

but once value reaches at grand-parent i want to pass that value to its another child component. i am doing it with `@input name:string` at child component. but don't know why i am not able to get that name in that child component.

parent =>

```
//html code
<personal-section (childName)="getName($event)"></personal-section>
<profile-section [name]="name"></name>

//inside profile.ts
 getName($event) {
    console.log(this.name);       // <--- upto this console, program works fine
    this.name= $event;
  }
```

child =>

```
 @Input() name: any;
 ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.name) {
      console.log('users name is ', this.name);    //<--this never prints.
    }
  }
```

but whenever i perform click event in grand-child's component, value perfectly reaches upto its grand-parent. but after that i am not able to get it in its another child i.e final destination ;)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Replace `getName($event)` with `getName(event)`, the $ is unnecessary in the controller. 2. Please do a console.log of `event` inside `getName(event)` and post the result to the question.

Comment: @Michael D Thank you for reply.As you said I have made changes.but I didn't get that value in that child  :)

Comment: I've posted an answer. Please see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the `getName($event)` in the controller with `getName(event)` is only a matter of convention.

Besides, if you only want to send the `name` variable from one child to another child, you could do it without involving the parent using custom variable. Try the following

Parent template

```html
<personal-section (childName)="profileSection1.setName($event)"></personal-section>
<profile-section #profileSection1></name>
```

The `@Input` decorator can then be removed from the `name` property in 'profile section' component.

Profile section component

```js
export class ProfileSectionComponent implements OnInit {
  name: any;

  public setName(name: any) {
    this.name = name;
    console.log('User name is ', this.name);
  }
  .
  .
}
```